# Get h:outputText in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsf

I have loaded some info in a `h:outputText` but now I want to click a button and trigger a JS function which will take that text from the outputText.

The structure is:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">
    <p:tab id="tabInvitator" title="Invitator">
         <h:form id="formInvitator">  
              <h:outputText id="inv" value="#{myController.selectedUsersFB}" />

...
```

But in the JS function **document.getElementsById("tabView:tabInvitator:formInvitator:inv")** doesn't work. It reinits the web app.

I just want to get that data and manipulate it in my JS function.
Any suggestions?

## **UPDATE:**

I've tried with what BalusC suggested, here is my try:

```
   function test(){
            var arr = document.getElementsByName("tabView:tabInvitator:formInvitator:inv");
            console.log(arr);
            console.log('Arr: '+arr);
            console.log('Length: '+arr.length);
```

The first log returns: [ ], 
The second one returns: Arr: [object NodeList], 
The thid one: Length: 0

Why does the log return different things? And now, how can I access to that object NodeList if that's suppose a text from h:outputText?

## **SOLUTION IN MY ANSWER BELOW**

Comment: Did you really use `getElementsById()`? There's namely a typo in that function name which might as well be result of carelessly formulating the question. Also, the quotes around the elemend ID are missing in the code.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you mean about typo... I set the value in inv, backed from managed bean (from selectedUsersFB) previously with another action, so that h:outputText has a value.

Comment: The `getElementsById()` function does not exist. If you have really used that, JavaScript should have given a clear error on that in the console like so `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementsById'`.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's why my web app is realoaded after executing that... so how could I manage it?

Comment: Use the right function name. It's shown in every JavaScript tutorial. Hint: according the HTML syntax rules, there can be **only one** element in the DOM with a given ID, not multiple elements.

Comment: I updated whith you suggestion, please check it if I'm on the right way... thanks.

Comment: You have an element ID, not element name there. There can be **only one** element in the DOM with a given ID. You should select an element (not elements!!) by ID. This is not a JSF/PrimeFaces problem, but just basic HTML/JS. You'd have had exactly the same problem when copypasting the JSF-generated HTML output into a static `.html` file and running it individually. Given this, I recommend to take a JSF pause and spend some effort and time in properly learning basic HTML/JS in order to better understand what JSF generates.

Comment: Ok, I tried with var arr = document.getElementById("tabView:tabInvitator:formInvitator:inv");
console.log(arr); but returns null

Comment: Great, your JS error is now solved! Next problem is actually unrelated, but yet simpler. Rightclick JSF page in browser, do *View Source* and look closer. There doesn't exist any element with exactly that ID! That totally explains why it returns `null`. Just fix the ID to match the one actually present in HTML source. Again, not a JSF/PrimeFaces problem at all, but just basic HTML/JS.

Comment: Perfect it worked, I spent some time managing HTML/JS and I realized that if the update is nested in forms, dialogs, etc. and you want to update something out of there, you have to set ":" before de id, as follows: update=":inv". Thanks, and please vote up my question, I don't know why has a negative vote :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a unique ID what I want to update so, the JS call would be: **document.getElementById**(...) (and not in plural -**getElementsById**-) since I will just return the data from an  which contain a value, normally text.

And following my example, if I want to update firstly the outputText and after that, get that info in the JS function I can do it in a row, first updating the field (this field I put it out of any tags), and oncomplete this, call the JS function:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">
  <p:tab id="tabInvitator" title="Invitator">
     <h:form id="formInvitator">
         <p:commandButton value="Invite" icon="ui-icon-comment"  update=":inv" oncomplete="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelectorSelected();"/>
     </h:form>
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>

<h:outputText id="inv" value="#{myController.selectedUsersFB}" />
```

and the Javascript function:

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelectorSelected() {
          var arr = document.getElementById("inv");
          console.log(arr.childNodes[0]);
          if(arr.childNodes[0]){
              console.log(arr.childNodes[0].data);
          }
          ...
}
```

Hope it helps someone ;)